# Battery status frozen

Tags: 14.04, battery

Mates,
I have a Gateway NE522 laptop.
The thing is that one day, I unplugged it before it was fully charged.
Since then, Ubuntu doesn't refresh it's battery status. While Windows does.

First I thought about BIOS, so updated it to it's last version. But still not refreshing battery status on Ubuntu.

---

I looked arround and found that the battery status archive isn't updating.
Well, it's actually updating every second, but doesn't change it's information.

It's content is:

```
present:                 yes
design capacity:         2500 mAh
last full capacity:      2331 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          14800 mV
design capacity warning: 161 mAh
design capacity low:     126 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  35 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  2170 mAh
model number:            AL12A32
serial number:            3455
battery type:            LION
OEM info:                SANYO
```

Does anyone know why might this happen?
Thanks in advance!

Pablo